# convert subtitle MKS to SRT in terminal?

Tags: video, video-editor, subtitle

convert subtitle MKS to SRT in terminal ?

How to ? because I can not edit my mks subtitle in ubuntu software that I use. just suport srt only

Answer (score 0):

Try out [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452268/extract-subtitle-from-mkv-files).

It worked back then, I see no reason why it should not work any more !